# JavaScript Regex for URL when the URL may or may not contain HTTP and WWW

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using JavaScript regex that will check for the URL.

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

I use this Regex to send messages to Twitter. What happens is that this makes sure that the URL contains WWW and/or HTTP.

But the problem is if the URL is like *Guaridan.com.uk* Twitter consideres it as a URL.

So how can I modify my Regex that it will not check for HTTP or WWW, meaning if it is there then it would not take any effect.

So it would match like *My.co.com* or *dummy.com.in*.

Comment: If you use jquery, why don't use use jquery's URL validation routines?

Comment: @fge i dont know anything about it. can you post some example

Comment: See here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url

Comment: Tested www.guardian.co.uk in the referred jQuery page, it does not validate.

Comment: @fge there is nothing in the jQuery API regarding url validation. Pehraps you are thinking about plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match just domain names you have to match almost any word plus ".", "_" and "-" signs. 
An approach may be match at least the root domains (.com,.net,.us,.co.uk,.es,.fr ... and so on) but the list will be huge. You may want to match just anything that has dot separated words, not that it is going to be a domain for sure but you might try connecting to it.

This regex: `([\d\w]+?:\/\/)?([\w\d\.\-]+)(\.\w+)(:\d{1,5})?(\/\S*)?`

will match:

- group 1 as protocol:// (optional)
- group 2 concat group 3 as domain
- group 3 is the top level domain
- group 4 as :port (optional)
- group 5 as query (optional)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery regular expression for www and http URL format.

Regular expression that accept *www* as well as *http* URL is given below:

```
var pattern = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(\/\S*)?/;
```

Regular expression that accept *www*, *http*, *abc.com* is given below:

```
var pattern = ([\d\w]+?:\/\/)?([\w\d\.\-]+)(\.\w+)(:\d{1,5})?(\/\S*)?
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you reformat your answer a little, putting the Regex into code brackets? Also recheck for typos, please.

Comment: its up to ur need where u using this Regex, just put urself code brackets or semicolon.like i add this Regex in my jqueryvalidation.js as                                         "url": {
                    "regex": /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(\/\S*)?/i,
                    "alertText": "* Invalid URL"
                }

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

`/^http:\/\/|(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/`

It's working exactly what peoples are want.

it takes with or with out `http://, https://,` and `www`.